# should the firebase object be a singleton in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

in the ios Swift implementation of the firebase sdk, should the firebase object be stored in a singleton?  Or does it manage and close connections automatically between views?

For instance, would creating a firebase object in each view create multiple socket connections?  Would it be more efficient to just keep one firebase object?

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://" + kFireBaseHost + ".firebaseio.com/")
```

Comment: Anything that is dispatched once is valid to be a singleton. But consider your use case, if you are creating multiple connections asynchronously while utilizing the same object, you will have a lot of issues. Although! firebase does allow for this with it's manager, just be cautious.

Comment: so in general different views will access different objects in firebase, but there might be some overlap, like in say accessing user information... so does it make sense to have a singleton manage overlapping connections... or is that already built into the firebase object so that it manages its own connections and pools connections to the same firebase paths?

Comment: Yes the manager will be able to handle async connections to the same paths. There also is an efficiency boost to this method, but also the consider the headaches that it may cause while handling your callbacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to make a singleton. Behind the scenes, Firebase manages a single connection and will dedupe appropriately if you have multiple Firebase objects or even if you have multiple observers at a single location. If you create a new Firebase object per view, so long as it's using the same base url, it will still use the same connection to the server.

While you don't need to manage how many Firebase objects you have, you should manage your observers. These do not get removed between views. To remove observers, you can use the `FirebaseHandle` returned by the `observeEventType` methods with the `removeObserverWithHandle:` method or call `removeAllObservers`. Note that both these methods require you call them at the same url location as the place you attached the observer (although it need not be the same object, just the same url). If you don't remove the observers, you might see them triggering from a view you left because someone else is changing the data. You can read more [in the docs under Detaching Blocks](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html).

This is all true for Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: so should keep a reference to the handle in the viewcontroller and removethem in view will disappear methods and reattach in the view will reappear... or is it better to just detach when the view will unload?

Comment: Yeah, I would deal with observer handle manipulation in viewWillAppear / viewWillDisappear rather than then load/unload methods since you only want to be syncing data when the view is showing.

Comment: Wait so why do you need to remove observers again? Because having multiple outstanding observers slows performance?

Comment: Essentially. The observers aren't cleaned up automatically, so they'll continue to exist and potentially hold onto other resources or trigger unexpectedly.