# Passing data to a Tab Bar attached ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I have the following structure of view controllers:

- Login *(segues to:)*

  - Tab Bar Controller *(button tap for:)*

    - Navigation Controller *(segues to:)*

      - Radar
    - Profile

I have an instance of Firebase which I'm creating at Login.viewDidLoad and passing from Login's prepareForSegue all the way to the RadarView:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destination: UIViewController? = segue.destinationViewController // UITabBarController

    if let tabBar = destination as? UITabBarController {
        let nav = tabBar.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        destination = nav.visibleViewController

    }

    if let destination = destination as? MyZoneRadarViewController {
        destination.firebase = firebase
    }
}
```

I want to pass this `Firebase` to the rest of my ViewControllers as well, how should I do that?

Is creating a singleton for this use case considered a good practice? I have more data to pass between the view controllers, what should I be doing?

Comment: Take a look at this, it has a solution for how to manage firebase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508615/should-the-firebase-object-be-a-singleton-in-swift

Comment: @Jay that's good to know indeed but my question is more general that firebase, I'm wondering given the above or similar typical view controllers segue hierarchy what is the common / recommended practice for passing data between objects. What happens when I change my view controllers structure the prepareForSegue does not seem like a robust way of implementing this. tnx.

Comment: IMO for things like this a singleton is perfect, make your own helper class that has a "shared" helper which will make your firebase calls.